# Hibernate non-standard joins gives org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Following are the tables in question

table1 -

```
CONTACT:

UNIVERSAL_ID (pk, Number(8,0)),
CONTACT_ID (pk, Number(4,0))
```

table2 -

```
ADDRESS:

UNIVERSAL_ID (pk, Number(8,0)),
ADDRESS_ID (pk, Number(4,0)),
ADDRESS_TYPE (fk, CHAR(3 BYTE))
```

table3 -

```
ADDRESS_TYPE:

ADDRESS_TYPE (pk, CHAR(3 BYTE))
```

trying to achieve the something similar to the following sql:

```
SELECT * FROM  Address A, CONTACT C WHERE A.UNIVERSAL_ID =C.UNIVERSAL_ID AND A.ADDRESS_TYPE='BB';
```

Entity classes:

Contact -

```
@Table(name = "CONTACT")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class ContactRole  {
@EmbeddedId
private ContactPK id;

@ManyToOne
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "(SELECT A.ADDRESS_TYPE FROM ADDRESS A WHERE A.UNIVERSAL_ID = UNIVERSAL_ID AND A.ADDRESS_TYPE = 'BB')",referencedColumnName = "ADDRESS_TYPE")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "UNIVERSAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "UNIVERSAL_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false))
})
private ContactAddress contactAddressBB;

}
```

Primary Key class

```
@Embeddable
public class ContactPK implements IPrimaryKey {

@Column(name = "UNIVERSAL_ID", nullable = false)
private Long uId;

@Column(name = "CONTACT_ID", nullable = false)
private Long contactId;

public ContactPK() {
}

public ContactPK(Long uId, Long contactId) {
    super();
    this.uId = uId;
    this.contactId = contactId;
}

}
```

Contact address -

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CONTACT")
public class ContactAddress extends BaseAddress {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Base Address -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class BaseAddress {

    @EmbeddedId
        private AddressPK id;

    @OneToOne
        @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_TYPE", referencedColumnName = "ADDRESS_TYPE")
        private AddressType addressType;

}
```

Address PK -

```
@Embeddable
public class AddressPK implements IPrimaryKey {

@Column(name = "UNIVERSAL_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long uId;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long addressId

    public AddressPK () {
    }

    public AddressPK (Long uId, Long addressId{
        super();
        this.uId = uId;
        this.addressId = addressId
    }

}
```

AddressType

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS_TYPE")
public class AddressType 
{
        @Id
        @Column(name = "ADDRESS_TYPE")
        private String addressType;
}
```

when the app initializes I get

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(ADDRESS_TYPE, UNIVERSAL_ID) of org.ContactRole.contactAddressBB referencing org.address.ContactAddress not mapped to a single property
```

I understand that the database design might have flaws but unfortunately i have to work with it, hence any help would be appreciated. Even a suggestion on a different way of doing it would be helpful if no direct solution is available.